# How to access array nested in JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON Object and I am trying to write a foreach loop to output each record in an array. This is my JSON Object code

```
{
  "name": "Takeaway Kings",
  "menu": {
    "starter": [
      {
        "name": "Samosas",
        "price": 3.5
      },
      {
        "name": "Chaat",
        "price": 1.99
      }
    ],
    "dessert": [
      {
        "name": "Kulfi",
        "price": 2.5
      },
      {
        "name": "Kheer",
        "price": 2.99
      }
    ],
    "main": [
      {
        "name": "Lamb Biryani",
        "price": 4.5
      },
      {
        "name": "Chicken Tikka Masala",
        "price": 5.99
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and this is my PHP code

```
$restaurant = json_decode(file_get_contents("restaurant.json"));
$restaurant->menu[0];
foreach($starters as $starter){
   $name = $starter->name;
   $price = $starter->price;
   //do something with it
   echo $name + " . " + $price;
}
```

at the moment nothing is being output

Comment: Where is `$starters` defined ?

Comment: Did you see the error message this code generates

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't use `$restaurant = json_decode(file_get_contents("post.php"), true);`? Because that way it would be easy for you to traverse the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at a `print_r($restaurant)` of the decodes JSON string **always a good start point when you are not sure of the JSON syntax**, you will see what structure it has.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => Takeaway Kings
    [menu] => stdClass Object
        (
            [starter] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Samosas
                            [price] => 3.5
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Chaat
                            [price] => 1.99
                        )

                )

            [dessert] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Kulfi
                            [price] => 2.5
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Kheer
                            [price] => 2.99
                        )

                )

            [main] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Lamb Biryani
                            [price] => 4.5
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Chicken Tikka Masala
                            [price] => 5.99
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Also in PHP the concatenation character is `.` and not `+`

```
$restaurant = json_decode(file_get_contents("restaurant.json"));

print_r($restaurant);

foreach($restaurant->menu->starter as $starter){
   echo $starter->name . ' = ' . $starter->price . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will produce the output

```
Samosas = 3.5
Chaat = 1.99
```

Comment: Thank you this explanation helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Replace menu[0] with menu and $starter->name with $starter[0]->name and $starter->price with $starter[0]->price like this:

```
$restaurant = json_decode(file_get_contents("restaurant.json"));
$starters = $restaurant->menu;

foreach($starters as $starter){
   $name = $starter[0]->name;
   $price = $starter[0]->price;
   //do something with it
   echo $name + " . " + $price;
}
```